# ng-repeat moves dom elements around, which breaks a ckeditor because it doesn't support having it's dom elements moved

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm trying have an ng-repeat which contains divs that include a CKEDITOR instance. The list is sortable by a few different properties. However, when the list is resorted, the CKEDITORs break because they don't support being moved around in the DOM. The only solution I can think of is to destroy the CKEDITOR instance before sort, and recreate them after. Is there any events on ng-repeat that can accomplish this?

plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tGnTdzvRl7xhEX7zYq4c?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried using any CKEDITOR directives (such as https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor) ? I would imagine that a proper directive bound to a model shouldn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: yes i am using that directive. this is not an issue related to directives or data, but specifically about dom elements being moved that dont support being moved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get this fixed eventually. Pretty easy now that I think about, but took me 3 days to realize it. Instead of trying to listen for events on ng-repeat, catch the event that is causing the data to be modified. For me, it was jquery UI sortable (angular directive.) In the controller add `$scope.$broadcast('unbind-ckeditor')` before the change, and then `$scope.$broadcast('rebind-ckeditor')` after it. In your angularjs directive for ckeditor, call `scope.$on('unbind-ckeditor', function() {instance.destroy /* instance is your ckeditor instance*/});` and then reload it in the rebind. Hope this helps someone.

Edit: 
Make sure the `$on('unbind-ckeditor'...` is only added to the scope once, or multiple sorts will throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me:

1. use `divArea` and not iframe, this will work with ng-repeat when the list changed.
2. using other textarea (hidden) and monitoring it as the `ng-sortable`+`ckeditor` broke the order of CKEditors.

in `ng-sortable` (who make the change in the list) I was added this code:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('rebind-ckeditor'); console.log("rebind")
```

and in CKEDITOR directive:

```
 scope.$on('rebind-ckeditor', function () {

    if (jQuery(element).data("loaded")) { 
         console.log("rebind");
         CKEDITOR.instances[element[0].id].destroy(); 
          jQuery(element).data("loaded", null); 
          element[0].value = $("textarea", element.parent())[1].value; // update manualy from the hidden textarea 
          onLoad();  //recreate CKE after textarea changed.
}
                })
```